Solving divergence and curl equations numerically
I've recently come to learn about Jefimenko's general solution for Maxwell's equations as well as the FDTD method in electromagnetic optics, and that has got me thinking whether I myself can solve Maxwell's equations numerically using Matlab or some similar software. Of course, the first step is to learn how to solve divergence and curl equations such as:
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=0$$
and
$$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}=0$$
but I can't find any resources online showing me how I can do this. Of course, the first equation is a bit easier to solve, since it's a linear PDE:
$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z}=0$$
and for the second equation, since the resulting curl will be a vector, perhaps I could divide the resolution in 3 linear equations (since all 3 componentes must be null).
Therefore, I'm currently facing 2 difficulties:

I don't know how to use the pdesolve package (and can't quite understand the online documentation)
I don't know whether my approach is efficient enough, although at least it makes sense


I don't know how to use the pdesolve package. Questions about using software packages are off-topic here.

It may be simpler to Fourier transform

If you only know one of the curl or the divergence of a vector field, that's not enough to specify a unique solution.  In general you need to know both.  If you're at the level where you've seen Jefimenko's equations then look up the "Helmholtz theorem" or "Helmholtz decomposition" for the mathematical details.

@MichaelSeifert ironically, I have studied the Helmholtz theorem but not Jefimenko's equations. I'm a 2nd year undergrad, so I guess my level is neither too high nor too low for these subjects. Since I'm interested in solving Maxwell's equations, however, I do know both the curl and the divergence of my fields. Nonetheless, i don't see why I can't calculate a solution for an equation such as $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=0$

You can use finite differences for numerically solving any PDE, so I don't know that pdesolve package is required.

No computers are required.
In ${\mathbb R}^3$ the field ${\bf E}$ satisfies ${\rm div}\,{\bf E}=0$ if and only if ${\bf E}= {\rm curl} \,{\bf A}$ for some vector field ${\bf A}$.
Similarly ${\bf E}$ satisfies ${\rm curl }\,{\bf E}=0$ if and only if ${\bf E}= {\rm grad}\, \phi$ for some scalar  field $\phi$.
In this way you have all explicit expressions for all solutions of your equations with no effeort required.

This sounds fantastic, but how can I find an explicit expression for E as you propose? Perhaps solving the Laplace equation for the potential?

Well you need to impose  boundary conditions if you want to select specific solutions

Right, but I mean how would I be able to solve $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E}=0$. Would it be as I propose in my post?
